# Can't connect to a localhost from kotlin and can connect to an online api

Tags: json, kotlin, gson, okhttp

So am having this problem i cant connect to my local host tho i can to an online one this is my code  i only get Failed to execute request in the debugger

```
 fun fetchJson() {
    println("Attempting to Fetch JSON")

    val url = "http://192.168.1.***:8*/demo/mysql/selector.php"

    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

    val client = OkHttpClient()
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            val resulta=response.body()?.string();

            println(resulta)
            println("Sucees")

            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

            val homeFeed = gson.fromJson(resulta, HomeFeed::class.java)

            runOnUiThread {
                recyclerView_main.adapter = MainAdapter(homeFeed)
            }


        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            println("Failed to execute request")
        }
    })
 }
```

i tried the 10.0.2.2 ip still the same i can access the file from my browser using that address in code

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you would at least post your exception's message. Maybe...

```
println("Failed to execute request: ${e.message}")
```

Also, please have a look at [Stack Overflow's question guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

But, just guessing...

This could have to do with your local server and how it does content negotiation.  If the `php` page really serves up JSON (and not rendered HTML), then you might try adding an `accept` header to your request.

```
val request = Request.Builder()
    .url(url)
    .header("Accept", "application/json")
    .build()
```